# TYPO3: Change protocol of menuitem to https

Tags: typo3

I have a HMENU and a login area. Inside the HMENU there is a login-area on menu level 3. All pages beneath this level 3 should be called with protocol https.

How can I change the protocol of the links in the menu? I could do this with a typoscript condition:

```
[PidInRootline = XXX]
lib.menu.3.NO {
   # ... what comes here?
}
[global]
```

I searched the web and there was this patch on a Typo3 ticket system which introduced `forceAbsoluteUrl` and `forceAbsoluteUrl.scheme`, but how do I get this into the HMENU?

---

### edit

I know that I cannot choose the menu with a typoscript condition like this. Since this menu will only show, if the PIDInRootline is true, it's ok.

I am also concerned about the links to the pages not protected from out of the protected pages. Every combination of `config.baseUrl` and `config.absRefPrefix` I tried fails in that there shall be links to the protected area with `https` protocol and to the public area with `http` protocol, regardless of whether I'm in the public or protected area.

Comment: Just change the protocol option in the `page properties` to HTTPS. You can even use `TCAdefault` to always set this field to HTTPS, so editors do not forget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work the way as you showed (sorry for bad news, but at least you'll save your time)

`[PidInRootline = XXX]` doesn't check the target's UID but UID of the page where you are at the moment.

I think, you'll need to write small extension for creating custom menu branch for https items, and combine it with the standard HMENU using `COA`

Comment: Don't think about the condition, I can handle that. I want to know, how can I change the protocol in the menu to https for certain menuitems

Comment: Create that items as links to `external URL` ang give there https links, then I think, you can use conditions to overwrite `baseURL` in that tree branch.

Comment: That's truth, it depends on how many items will be there. If it's just 3 or 5 - you can consider that scenario, otherwise if the 'https folder` is subject to often change you'll need to write custom extension. Anyway from my long practise it looks that pages like 'login page' or 'change password' changes so rare, that 'hardcoding' the URLs should not be a problem, It depends on your needs but even with TYPO3 it's sometimes better idea to stop thinking: "it has to be flexible forever" - although it's CMS you can consider some parts of it to be just constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can force every page to a specific protocol in the page properties. In the tab *Behaviour* you can find the field **protocol** with the following options:

- Default: This means use the current protocol
- https: Force this page to https
- http: Force this page to http

Switch all pages you want to have with https and you are done.

However in current days you should switch all pages to https which can be done best in `.htaccess`.